# Tasks missing from capistrano unicorn task list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, unicorn

A coworker is getting different results for `cap -vT unicorn` compared to me, for the same version of capistrano, and the same Rails app:

```
app_name coworker$ cap -vT unicorn
cap unicorn:add_worker    # Add a new worker
cap unicorn:duplicate     # Duplicate Unicorn
cap unicorn:reload        # Reload Unicorn
cap unicorn:remove_worker # Remove amount of workers
cap unicorn:restart       # Restart Unicorn
cap unicorn:show_vars     # Debug Unicorn variables
cap unicorn:shutdown      # Immediately shutdown Unicorn
cap unicorn:start         # Start Unicorn master process
cap unicorn:stop          # Stop Unicorn
```

me:

```
app_name agrimm$ cap -vT unicorn
cap unicorn:graceful_stop # Unicorn graceful shutdown
cap unicorn:reload        # Reload Unicorn
cap unicorn:start         # Start Unicorn
cap unicorn:stop          # Stop Unicorn
Extended help may be available for these tasks.
Type `cap -e taskname' to view it.
```

`config/deploy.rb` has `require 'capistrano-unicorn'`

My suspicion is that I'm not getting the tasks from capistrano unicorn, but what's going wrong? How do I diagnose the problem?

Comment: Is it the same version of capistrano-unicorn?